# How do I continue this surface integral?

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I tried to solve this. After find normal vector, I don't know how know how do I continue this.. Question is in this pic. =>][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKZGy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. For a problem like this, always start with a sketch.  Sketch the direction of the vector field at a few points on the surface.
2. At some point you will probably want to switch to cylindrical coordinates.  You will be able to write $\hat{n}$ as $\hat{r}$ (or $\hat{\rho}$ if you prefer) and the dot product will be easy, too.
3. Pick a value for $dS$.  That will depend on what you have for your integrand (the dot product).
4. Set up limits of integration.  That will depend on your $dS$.